# Can I direct Git to treat file names starting with the same string as merge conflict?

Tags: git, github

My git repo has a folder which contains database migrations scripts, named like this:

```
001 create a table.sql
002 add some data.sql
003 create another table.sql
...
```

There are never supposed to be two database migrations with the same number (because that would throw off a custom migration tool). For example, the following is not supposed to happen:

```
065 do something written by developer a.sql
065 something else written by developer b.sql
```

Is there any way to tell git to treat the above as a merge conflict, although the files have different names?

So basically, for the purpose of merging, git should treat both files as just `065.sql` or even just `065`. This would prevent an automatic merge and alert the developer that they're about to create a duplicate migration number.

Can this somehow be done in git, or will this require custom logic in my CI tool?

Comment: Git itself can't, git hooks, like pre-commit, can intervene though.

Comment: I'd suggest using a timestamp instead of incrementing your own ordinal, conflicts become substantially less likely.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. The ordinals specify execution order. How would a timestamp help?

Comment: Timestamps are also ordered...

Comment: @jonrsharpe. The timestamp of what though? Edits can be made to scripts regardless of the order in which they are executed

Comment: Of creation of the new migration. You shouldn't be editing old migrations anyway, because that defeats the point.